# How to touched validate email control using pattern in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to ask on how to access the email pattern error to validate using it by `hasError` in angular 2 so that I can apply `invalid` class on my input field.
Below is registration.component.html code:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="Email" type="email" [formControl]="myCustomForm.controls['email']" [ngClass]="{invalid: myCustomForm.controls['email'].touched && myCustomForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')}">
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
</div>
```

Below is registration.component.ts code:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private ASD: AppStartupData, private af: AngularFire) {
this.registration_id;
this.svc_AppStartupData = ASD;
this.myCustomForm = fb.group({
  "first_name": ['', Validators.required],
  "middle_name": [''],
  "last_name": ['', Validators.required],
  "gender": ['', Validators.required],
  "email": ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0–9_.+\\-\\]+@[a-zA-Z0–9-]+.[a-zA-Z0–9\\-\\.]+$")])],
  "password": ['', Validators.required],
  "telephone": ['', Validators.required],
  "cities": ['', Validators.required],
  "address": ['', Validators.required],
  "dob": ['', Validators.required]
});
}
```

Comment: `ng-invalid` is added automatically.

Comment: `[formControl]="myCustomForm.controls['email']"` should be `[formControl]="myCustomForm.get('email')"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer its shows me `ng-valid` when I put invalid email like `ahmer` without `@xyz.com`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your second comment doesn't take any effect.

Comment: It's not a fix for your problem, just a hint.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer still waiting for an answer

Comment: I don't understand the question. I passed. Why don't you go with the `ng-invalid` class? (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your time and reply. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my question. I find out the way how to validate email control in angular 2 ontouched. Below is my code which I have been used inside my class in registration.component.ts

```
customValidation(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (!control.value.match(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/)) {
        return { invalidSku: true };
    }
}
```

and in my registration.component.html I put:

```
[ngClass]="{invalid: myCustomForm.controls['email'].touched && myCustomForm.controls['email'].hasError('invalidSku')}"
```